# Как настроить запуск virtualenv перед стартом Django в Pycharm 5?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Есть проект на Django и Virtualenv для этого проекта.

Как запустить сначала venv потом проект в Pycharm Pro 5?

OS Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте в качестве дефолтного интерпретатора для проекта ваше Virtualenv:

```
File -> Settings -> Project: some_project -> Project Interpreter
```

Или настройте ваше Virtualenv в качестве интерпретатора конкретной конфигурации запуска проекта:

```
Run -> Edit Configuration... -> Django Server -> Python Interpreter
```